# Count occurrences in binary tree in C

Tags: c, struct, tree, binary-tree, nodes

```
struct tree{
    struct node* root;
};

typedef struct tree* Tree;

struct node{
   int key;
   struct node* left;
           struct node* right;
};
typedef struct node* node;
```

My problem is that the function I need to implement requires as a parameter a Tree and not a Node.

```
int count_occurrences(Tree t, int k){}
```

I know how to implement this function if the first parameter was of type Node, but since it needs a type Tree I can't figure it out how to pass the type Tree parameter in the recursive calls.

EDIT: Also there is another problem. I can't access struct fields directly since they are declared in another file (school project). I have access to some functions like getting the root of a tree, left or right child of a node etc

```
Tree newtree();
int treeempty(Tree t);
Node root(Tree t);
int readInfo(Node v);
void setInfo(Node v, int x);
Node leftChild(Node v);
Node rightChild(Node v);
```

Comment: You can have a frontend function that takes a tree and a recursive function that takes a node. Call the recursive function with the root node from the frontend.

Comment: Why do you need recursive calls ? Simply loop trough the tree starting at root until you reach the end (which is probably indicated by `right` beeing NULL). Also, hiding the fact that something is a pointer type with a typedef can be confusing.

Answer (score 2):

One straightforward way is to create a helper function:

```
int count_occurrences_helper(node d, int k) {
  /* You already know how to implement this. */
}

int count_occurrences(Tree t, int k) {
  return count_occurrences_helper(t->root, k);
}
```

Comment: I can't access struct fields directly since they are in another file c (can't move them, this is for school). I have access to some functions like getting the root of a tree, getting left child of the root or right child

Comment: What do you mean that you can't access struct fields directly?  It doesn't matter what file they're defined in.

Comment: for example I cant do t->root, but I have to call the function root(t)

Comment: In that case, just replace `return count_occurrences_helper(t->root, k);` by `return count_occurrences_helper(root(t), k);` and the solution will allow to  call `count_occurrences_helper()` as recursive function.

Comment: The problem remains because in count_occurrences_helper I can't access node->key etc.

Comment: But you have written before **"I know how to implement this function if the first parameter was of type Node"**... So the first parameter of the `count_occurrences_helper()` function is a `node d`... What is the problem ?